# Optimal database access for continued and multiple CRUD operations

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

Before I ask this question, I am sure this has been asked before but I had a hard time filling in proper terms to find this. As a result I was unable to find any information. So I apologize if it has been asked before.

Consider the following scenario:
A game server is backed by an SQL database for player storage and logging. Every time a player logs in data is retrieved and written. Also every few seconds (20 seconds or something) the logs are written to the database including changed data about the players.

I am wondering how to handle these connections. Keeping the connection open forever is a bad idea because the MySQL server closes it after "inactivity".

Opening the connection each time works but I am wondering if it is the best approach or is there another possibility?

Comment: You can configure the timeout after which the database closes the connection.

Comment: Is it healthy to keep the database connection open for days? Maybe I should figure out a way that closes the connection if there is no activity for a few minutes and keep it open if there is.

Comment: I don't think keeping it open for days makes sense. What would be the advantage? Even reopening it every minute should not be a performance issue. I wouldn't set the timeout to more than 5 minutes since the number of open connections is limited and you could easily run into problems if you're hording dead connections or forget to close them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what [connection pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) are good for. Try [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/), its extremly fast. You can use it on top of plain JDBC, as well as JPA or O/R mappers. It will keep a set of connections open (pooling) and manage their **reuse**, if you have a lot of concurrent connections.

If you have to store logs in the database, there are several logging frameworks, that already have funtions to do so. For example [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) has a DBAppender that works on top of connection pools:

> "..., sending 500 logging requests to the aforementioned MySQL database takes around 0.5 seconds, for an average of 1 millisecond per request, that is a tenfold improvement in performance." ([source](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#ConnectionPooling))

Comment: Excellent. I was also thought about **Connection pool**. I like the way you give alternatives for managing connections & logging. +1